# Where do classes go in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC. I made 3 classes. I was wondering where should I store these classes? From my understanding of MVC they should not be store in the Controller section. Is that right?

Comment: "Class" is (a little bit) vague in this context. But they probably belong to Model part of Model / View / Controller

Comment: What do these classes do, you might want to show an example.

Comment: If by class you mean the logic of the project, it should goto BLL(Business Logic LAYER) If you mean Model which may be, DTO, POCO, or ViewModel, It may go in BLL or DataLayer, or Repository Or even the presentation layer. Your question is very vague

Comment: @ShayanNafisi Sorry if I didn't explain my self very well. I made a calendar class which calculates days between two dates. Example, how many days for a wednesday event etc. Based on days, then the event gets added to the database. So my question was where would I save those kind of class files. And where would I instantiate the object? In the controller or in the model?

Comment: that is the logic of the program. I would create a layer as BLL(Business Logic Layer) put that class in there and reference it in presentation layer or wherever else it is used. I will paste this as an answer in the question too.

Comment: I knew exactly what you were asking trant. I'm just getting started in MVC, and like you I wanted to know where to put a few of my tools I've used in the past. Thanks for asking this. (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of classes are you asking about?

Controllers go in the Controllers folder, Views go in the Views folder, Models go in the Models folder.
In general that is all that should be in these respective folders.

If you need some "helpers" outside of this (e.g. a factory class) it's usually recommended to place them in a separate folder (or folders) at the same level as the Controllers, Views, and Models folders. However, in general as much of your logic as possible should be in the controller (unless you have a separate middle tier, of course).

**Update based on comment:**

> I am making a calendar application. So when the user types the start
>   date and end date, my class will calculate the actual number of days.
>   Ex How many days for a Monday Wed Fri event. Then the event will be
>   added to the database. So can I instantiate this object(one which
>   calculates the days and adds to the database) in the controller and
>   then pass it to the model? Or should the logic be done at the model
>   layer?

I would do this in the controller. The flow of MVC starts with the controller, which populates the model, then passes the model to the view and returns the view.

However, you should also distinguish between *domain model* and *view model*. Your view model really should not have anything to do with the database; it's only there to populate the view. The domain model could have dual purposes, though I prefer to keep them separate.

Either way, actual database access logic, if it's not in the middle tier, fits more appropriately in the controller and not in a model. I would instantiate your helper object in the controller and have it do what it needs to do in the controller; a database access object generally should not need to be passed to a view model.

Of course this is generally speaking and there may be exceptions that work better for some situations.

Comment: I am making a calendar application. So when the user types the start date and end date, my class will calculate the actual number of days. Ex How many days for a Monday Wed Fri event. Then the event will be added to the database. So can I instantiate this object(one which calculates the days and adds to the database) in the controller and then pass it to the model? Or should the logic be done at the model layer?

Comment: Thanks mayabelle that helps a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answered your question you can click the checkmark next to the answer and it will turn green. :)

Answer (score 2):

The controller section is for controllers, so it doesn't make sense to store other types of classes there. You can pretty much store them everywhere you want though. Just make folders or categorize them however you want. It all comes down to your own conventions and style.

Think about what the classes do, and how it makes sense to categorize them.

Comment: I am making a calendar application. So when the user types the start date and end date, my class will calculate the actual number of days. Ex How many days for a Monday Wed Fri event. Then the event will be added to the database. So can I instantiate this object(one which calculates the days and adds to the database) in the controller and then pass it to the model? Or should the logic be done at the model layer?

Comment: Both approaches are ok. It's all about personal preference. Some people prefer models with no logic, but its not a strict requirement

Comment: Thanks TGH! Which one would prefer? Instantiating the object in the controller or instantiating the object in the model?

Comment: No strong preference. One argument in favor of separating it from the model is that you can more easily reuse it elsewhere if needed. It can also be easier to unit test the logic since you have less dependencies if it's decoupled

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to model classes, so put them in the `Models`.

Answer (score 0):

I can strongly recommend you to investigate some time in object oriented programming principles (SOLID), and after that, try to understand how the architecture of your "Real World" MVC Web application should look like. Ik explicitly mention "Real World", because many of the tutorials you will find on the internet are simplified representations of technical possibilities, but they do not learn you how this will fit in your own application. I recently put a lot of time in these two aspects, and it helped me a lot. Not saying i have all the knowledge now, but i do get a lot better understanding.

As an answer to your question: I think those classes should not be in the controller folder, since they are not controllers. I think they belong in your Business Layer (can be seperate project), because they are responsible for some business logic. Also, adding the event to the database does not belong in the same class as the date calculation, because this will violate SRP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). This should be in a seperate class which sits in your Data Layer(can be another seperate project), and you can call this from your Business Layer.

Another interesting thing to read about is this anti-pattern called the fat controller (http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2008/12/03/the-fat-controller/).

Answer (score 0):

If that is the logic of the program, I would create a layer as BLL(Business Logic Layer) put that class in there and reference it in presentation layer or wherever else it is used.